# How to get rid of lines surrounded by empty spaces?

Tags: python, text, nlp

I have a text that looks something like this:

```
text
text
text


to remove

text
text
text


to remove
 

text
text
text
```

There are blocks of uninterupted text and I need to remove the lines that look like 'to remove' in the above example, there are 2 empty lines above them and 1 empty line below. Is there someway to programmatically remove those lines together with spaces that surround them in Python?

Comment: Is it always this format? (2 empty rows one with text and one empty) except from the wanted text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
l=[]
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        l.append(i)

m=set()
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i].replace(' ', '')=='\n':
        m.add(i)
for i in range(1, len(l)-1):
    if l[i-1].replace(' ', '')=='\n' and l[i+1].replace(' ', '')=='\n':
        m.add(i)

result=[l[i] for i in range(len(l)) if i not in m]

with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in result:
        f.write(i)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please point out how to remove one line below each white space?

Answer (score 2):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are a powerful instrument for pattern search and replacement.

Assuming the text is in `text` variable,

```
import re

re.sub('\n{3}[^\n]+\n{2}', '\n', text, re.M)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function .translate(). The translate() function deleates white space from a string. Here is a tutorial: [https://www.journaldev.com/23763/python-remove-spaces-from-string#:~:text=Python%20String%20strip()%20function%20will%20remove%20leading%20and%20trailing%20whitespaces.&text=If%20you%20want%20to%20remove,or%20rstrip()%20function%20instead](https://www.journaldev.com/23763/python-remove-spaces-from-string#:%7E:text=Python%20String%20strip()%20function%20will%20remove%20leading%20and%20trailing%20whitespaces.&text=If%20you%20want%20to%20remove,or%20rstrip()%20function%20instead).
or

```py
import string
s = "Text     Text     Text"
print(s.translate({ord(c): None for c in string.whitespace}))
```

It will print out `TextTextText`

Here's an example: https://repl.it/repls/AwfulAmusedGlitches#main.py.

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expressions should work. However, here I thought maybe this might be a chance to show an example of using [the walrus operator `:=` in python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html): to find the location of a multiline pattern within a list comprehension.
It might be useful in future if the pattern is more complicated.

```
text = """
text
text
text


to remove

text
text
text


to remove
 

text
text
text
"""

curr = ("", "", "", "")

positions = [
  (i-4, i) 
  for i, line in enumerate(text.split("\n"))
  if (curr := (curr[1], curr[2], curr[3], line.strip())) == ("", "", "to remove", "")
]
```

The resulted `positions` here is a list of tuples indicating the range of separator pattern:
`[(3, 7), (10, 14)]`

Yeah, it is too complicated already! Bear with me with for this final bit.  You can use the list of ranges as a filter with `any()`, to check if a line is not in any of the separator ranges:

```
remained_lines = [
  line
  for pos, line in enumerate(text.split("\n"))
  if not any([i<= pos < j for i, j in positions])
]
new_text = "\n".join(remained_lines)
```

In conclusion, use regular expressions whenever you can, however, here I have some new and old pythonic features that might come handy for future readers with more strange separator situations.

Answer (score -1):

**This should solve your problem:**

```
text = "text \ntext \ntext \n\n\nto remove \n \n \ntext \ntext"
text = "".join([s for s in text.strip().splitlines(True) if s.strip()])

print(text)
```

And the output would be like this:

```
text
text
text
to remove
text
text
```